# How to include one positional argument into argparse mutually exclusive group?

Tags: python, argparse

I know that does not make sense multiple positional arguments into a mutually exclusive group because you can't say who is who. But I need to include ONE positional argument into that.

What I need:

```
$ myprogram -h
usage: myprogram [-h] [--delete value | --update value | value]
```

Where positional `value` is the default action (kind of "--include"). (`myprogram` without arguments must be valid too).

My first attempt (this doesn't works):

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--delete', metavar='value')
group.add_argument('--update', metavar='value')
group.add_argument('value')
```

Is that possible?

---

Second attempt:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--delete', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('--update', action='store_true')
group.add_argument('--insert', action='store_true', default=True)
group.add_argument('value')
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'd do this a little bit differently:

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.set_defaults(mode='insert')
group.add_argument('--delete', action='store_const', dest='mode', const='delete')
group.add_argument('--update', action='store_const', dest='mode', const='update')
group.add_argument('--insert', action='store_const', dest='mode', const='insert')
parser.add_argument('value', nargs='?')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

If you additionally want to make `program --delete` (with no `value` option) fail, add

```
if args.mode != 'insert' and args.value:
    parser.error("can't {} without a value argument".format(args.mode))
```

Note that this will mean that `program --insert` (with no `value`) still works. You could avoid this with a little more effort by having the default `mode` be `None`, doing the check above with `args.mode is not None`, and then doing `if args.mode is None: args.mode = 'insert'` or similar.

Answer (score 3):

Your syntax is more clearly described as:

```
myprogram {--insert|--update|--delete} value
```

where `--insert` defaults to True and value is required.

`argparse` can make you feel like your desired syntax must fit its model when something like

```
if args.insert and (args.update or args.delete):
    parser.print_help()
```

is much more obvious.

**Added in response to comment:**

Here is pseudo-code (meaning I didn't test it) which shows how I would implement this:

```
parser.add_argument('--insert', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--update', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('--delete', action='store_true')
parser.add_argument('value')
args = parser.parse_args(sys.argv)
if ((args.insert and args.delete) or
    (args.insert and args.update) or
    (args.update and args.delete)):
    # can't pick more than one, complain and quit 
elif not (args.update or args.delete):
    # they specified no action so assume insert
    args.insert = True

# now one and only one of insert/update/delete is
# True and args.value contains the argument
```

I hope that makes things more clear.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I didn't fully understand you: I did add '--insert' argument and put default to True. So, this part worked. But calling `myprogram` without arguments fail because `value` is required. Maybe I didn't understand you at all...

Comment: Please update your question with the new code or open a new question as I can't read what I can't see. I suspect that you tried to to keep the mutually_exclusive_group which isn't needed.

Comment: I've tested your solution and the user can't choose `-h` because `value` is required. Besides that, in my understanding, those if-blocks are doing exactly the job of a mutually exclusive group.

Answer (score 3):

Make the positional argument optional (with '?')

```
parser = ArgumentParser()
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('--delete', metavar='value')
group.add_argument('--update', metavar='value')
group.add_argument('value', nargs='?')
```

usage is then:

```
usage: ipython [-h] [--delete value | --update value | value]
```