# Python 2.7 argparse: How to nest optional mutally exclusive arguments properly?

Tags: python, python-2.7, command-line-arguments, argparse

My Program should include the following options, properly parsed by [argparse](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html):

1. purely optional: `[-h, --help]` and `[-v, --version]`
2. mutually exclusive: `[-f FILE, --file FILE]` and `[-u URL, --url URL]`
3. optional if `--url` was chosen: `[-V, --verbose]`
4. required if either `--file` or `--url` was chosen: `[-F, --format FORMAT]`

The desired usage pattern would be:

```
prog.py [-h] [-v] [-f FILE (-F FORMAT) | -u URL [-V] (-F FORMAT) ]
```

with the `-F` requirement applying to both members of the mutually exclusive group.
Not sure if it rather be a [positional](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857953/how-to-include-one-positional-argument-into-argparse-mutually-exclusive-group).

So it should be possible to run:

```
prog.py -u "http://foo.bar" -V -F csv
```

and the parser screaming in case i forgot the `-F` (as he's supposed to).

What i've done so far:

```
parser = ArgumentParser(decription='foo')

group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()    
group.add_argument('-f','--file', nargs=1, type=str, help='')
group.add_argument('-u','--url', nargs=1, type=str, help='')    

parser.add_argument('-V','--verbose', action='store_true', default=False, help='')
parser.add_argument('-F','--format', nargs=1, type=str, help='')
```

Since it has a 'vanilla mode' to run without command line arguments, all arguments must be optional.

How can i implement points 3. and 4. into my code?

EDIT:
I tried `-f` and `-u` as subparsers, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11760578/argparse-arguments-nesting), but subcommands seem to be treated like positionals and the parser gives me an `error: too few arguments` if i run it without arguments.

Comment: have you considered [docopt](http://docopt.org/)? The disadvantage is that it allows option values to start with `-` [e.g., `"-f a -F -u"` (the format is "-u" here)](https://gist.github.com/zed/b94e3e9945debe25826d)

Comment: Is one of `-f` and `-u` required? If so, I'm picturing a solution involving subcommands or positional arguments.

Comment: @chepner: no, they aren't. i want the program to also run without args and options, so it will start a user dialog or even a GUI

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `docopt` looks great, i'll dig into it and report if it suits my needs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use of nargs=2 and tuple metavar approximates your goal

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
group = parser.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
group.add_argument('-f','--file', nargs=2, metavar=('FILE','FORMAT'))
group.add_argument('-u','--url', nargs=2, metavar=('URL','FORMAT'))
parser.add_argument('-V','--verbose', action='store_true',help='optional with url')
```

which produces:

```
usage: PROG [-h] [-f FILE FORMAT | -u URL FORMAT] [-V]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -f FILE FORMAT, --file FILE FORMAT
  -u URL FORMAT, --url URL FORMAT
  -V, --verbose         optional with url
```

This requires the format along with filename or url, it just doesn't require the `-F`.  As others noted `-V` can be ignored in the `-f` case.

---

> I tried -f and -u as subparsers, as described here, but subcommands seem to be treated like positionals and the parser gives me an error: too few arguments if i run it without arguments.

In the latest version(s) subcommands are no longer treated as required positionals.  This was, as best I can tell, a side effect of changing the error message to be more informative.  Instead of `_parse_known_args` doing a:

```
    if positionals:
        self.error(_('too few arguments'))
```

it scans `_actions` to see which are required, and then lists them by name in the error message.  This is discussed in http://bugs.python.org/issue9253 .  I know this change is in development (3.4), and may also be in 3.3.

---

Answer (score 2):

These points can enforced in `optparse` using a [callback](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#callback-example-6-variable-arguments) method when a certain option is present.

However, in `argparse` these are not available.

You can add a  [subparser](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers) for the `url` and the `file` sub-option, and parse these seperatly.
from the help:

> Note that the object returned by parse_args() will only contain attributes for
>   the main parser and the subparser that was selected by the command line 
>   (and not any other subparsers). So in the example above, when the a command 
>   is specified, only the foo and bar attributes are present, and when the b command
>   is specified, only the foo and baz attributes are present.

But I would just properly document the usage, and just ignore the arguments that are not 
applicable.

e.g. let these two command lines behave exactly the same:

```
prog.py -f FILE -V
prog.py -f FILE
```

Comment: `argparse` has built-in support for options with a variable number of arguments, as well as custom actions to process the argument(s) of a given option. However, I agree that in this case, it is simplest to just allow `-V` and ignore it if `-f` is used.

Comment: `optparse` is deprecated and `argparse` is its replacement. See: https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#upgrading-optparse-code